# publishing links in menu makes them disappear

Tags: routes

I am using drupal 6. I created a bunch of pages and made them unpublished. I then created a menu with links to those unpublished pages. When each menu item's path was set to those pages, the menu item would disappear from the menu. I was told not to worry, this was only because the pages were unpublished, once they would be published they would reappear.
When I was ready to publish the pages, I initially went to each page, clicked the edit tab, edited the "publish" section to publish the pages and they did indeed reappear. But as there were a lot of pages, I wanted to be more efficient. I went to the content page, searched for my unpublished pages and published them all at once. While they did all become published, none of those newly published menu items showed up in my menu again. Why was this so?